# Is it faster to walk backwards or roll backwards?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I like to BIotic Charge and back up repeatedly to finish off weak enemies without wasting bullets. Pressing Run while moving back does a quick roll but has a slow recovery. Visually, I can't really tell which is faster.

Do I back up faster if I just walk or is rolling faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran some tests on a straight shot between two points:

- Sprinting - 8 seconds
- Rolling - 12 seconds
- Walking - 12 seconds

It's clear that sprinting is the fastest of the three, and if you're going to roll, you might as well just walk :)

Comment: Good work! I tested this myself but got inconsistent results...and I couldn't operate my phone's stop watch + my controller at the same time.

Comment: @BenBrocka It took judicious application of some additional appendages, although thinking about it now I could have just asked my wife for help...

Comment: clearly a rube-goldberg machine would have been a more appropriate solution than just having another person use a stopwatch

Answer (score 0):

They are approximately the same speed. Rolling is slightly faster, but then you have to get up which slows you down. You will net a VERY small gain by rolling backwards on open ground. However during a roll you have less control of direction and so can lose ground if you hit a wall or obstruction.